# How do people make GIFs from Android Studio?

Tags: android

Stuff like this. I'm not sure how to quite do that outside of a screen capture program. Or perhaps they are using an emulator with that function?

[GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsTjh.gif)

Comment: Android Studio (and command-line tools) can record videos of Android apps as MP4. From there, use tools to generate an animated GIF from the MP4. Leastways, that's how I'd try to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an app called screencast pre installed in Android. Use that to record screen actions and then convert it to a gif using an online software